# How to pass a function as a parameter to void function pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, void-pointers

I am new to function pointers .
I have written a function which can take pointer to a function.

```
 register_agent( void (*agent)())
```

I want to pass a pointer of the function

```
 registry_agent
```

as a parameter to

```
 register_agent
```

Can anyone pls suggest how do I do this in C. Also explain the concept behind

Answer (score 0):

It cant be done in C as you will have an infinite-length function declaration:

```
void ra(void (*r)(void (*r)(void (*r)(void .......))))
```

(assuming that you want to declare it giving the parameter list)

Comment: Note that the question asks about two functions with different (but confusingly similar) names: `registry_agent()` and `register_agent()` (`registRY` vs `registER`).  And presumably, the register function can be used to register numerous functions, though it is not clear whether they share the same signature or not.